# updating an object in R for nycflights13

Tags: r, tibble

I have the following code:

```
Q3 <- flights
minimum_distance <- arrange(flights, distance) %>% select(origin, dest, distance)
colnames(minimum_distance)[3] <- "min_dist"
head(distinct(minimum_distance), 5)
```

It outputs as: (which is what I am expecting)

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  origin dest  min_dist
  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>
1 EWR    LGA         17
2 EWR    PHL         80
3 JFK    PHL         94
4 LGA    PHL         96
5 EWR    BDL        116
```

However, I am expecting the Q3 object to update with this info, but it has 336776 obs of 10 variables, which is not correct.  How do I get the Q3 object to reflect the tibble correctly?
[image]

Expecting Q3 to have 5 objects with 3 variables

Comment: What is `flights_minimum_distance`?  `Q3 <-  arrange(flights, distance) %>% select(origin, dest, distance)
> dim(Q3)
[1] 336776      3`

Comment: are you looking at the right objects? You assign `flights` to `Q3`. The operations on `minimum_distance` are based on the (orignial) `flights` dataframe. This is what you inspect with your `head()` call. Thus, when looking again at `Q3`, you will see the original flights table you assigned to it

Comment: I was overthinking this.  It is doing what I need it to by assigning Q3 to the head() line.  Thanks